Calling a python library which calls a rest enpoint in Airflow DAG throws connection timeout error
I have a python library, which calls a specific rest endpoint. But using that inside an airflow dag throws connection timeout error. Do we have to do something additional to allow connection to endpoints outside airflow?

You can either use the Airflow Http operator (with a connection to your endpoint) or the requests module in a callable function with the Python operator. Please share your code snippet when asking questions. Are you running airflow on docker, you need to make sure that your endpoint can be reached from docker in that case.

Also if you are trying on mac OS you can check with this workaround https://bugs.python.org/issue28342
